# WebView fails to render certain webpages

Tags: android, webview, html

I'm trying to show 2 webpages in WebViews. The 1st one works fine, but the 2nd will result in a blank screen.
This happens on Android 4.2.2, if I run this on a Lollipop it works fine. Moreover, I tried saving the page to the assets folder in my project and it could load properly that way.
Here are the URLs I am trying to load:
1. http://www.taiwanjobs.gov.tw/mobileApp/docDetail_frame.aspx?uid=411&pid=221&docid=141
2. http://www.taiwanjobs.gov.tw/mobileApp/docList_frame.aspx?uid=412&pid=221

Here is my code:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code...
I think you have to override the urlloading as below code...

```
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);


   private class webViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... turns out the issue was from the webpage itself,
WebView in Android 4.2.2 just wasn't supporting it,
I tried opening it with the web browser on an Android 4.2.2 emulator,
same results.